Dance of The Knights puzzle
Here is a puzzle sold in the late 80s and 90s in shops and market stalls.
Now in this digital age, it can easily be shared.  Hope you like it!
It says 'Rearrange the marbles between the two patterns using the knight's move in chess.
40+ moves poor, 35-40 fair, 30-35 good, 26-28 excellent and *** 24 moves least possible ***.


Rot13(Vf ebgngvat gur jubyr obneq pbafvqrerq gb or n serr, be n fvatyr zbir)?

@WeatherVane Rotating the whole board is not a knight's move.

Update I got 26

@PDT  Hope you are enjoying it!  Did you make a version on a chess board or something?

No I did it on penpa+ Struggling to get 24 it seems impossible

@PDT it can be done, if it were too easy it wouldn't be fun!  All the best with it


 

       R1 G1 Y1 B1
       R2 G2 Y2 B2
       R3 G3 Y3 B3
       R4 G4 Y4 B4

 

Moves 1-4:

 
          B1
       R1 G1 Y1 G2
       R2    Y2 B2
       R3 G3    B3
       Y3 G4 Y4 B4
             R4
 

Moves 5-10:

 
          B1    G1
       R1 B2 Y1 G2
       R2       G3
       Y2       B3
       Y3 G4 R3 B4
       Y4    R4
 

Moves 11-14:

 
          B1    G1
       B4 B2 Y1 G2
       R2       G3
       Y2       B3
       Y3 G4 R3 R1
       Y4    R4
 

Moves 15-20:

 

       B4 B2 Y1 G2
       B1 B3    G3 G1
    Y4 Y2    R2 R4
       Y3 G4 R3 R1

 

Moves 21-24:

 

       B4 B2 G1 G2
       B1 B3 G4 G3
       Y2 Y1 R2 R4
       Y3 Y4 R3 R1

 


I guess I took too long making mine pretty?

@DanielMathias You calling mine ugly?!?! ;-D

Yours shows the order, that's important in this puzzle.  Well done both of you!

An optimal solution with 24 moves.

 

First moves:

 

Second moves:

 


Well done both of you!
